# Build input file cannot be found on Xcode13.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-m1

Question for Building

I'm using m1 mac machine.
I trying to run my app no my device.
But somehow an error message appeared saying, "Build input files cannot be found".

Detailed:

```
CopySwiftLibs /Users/evanlu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/finwork-dbwrwhkrmlwsysdijoivlfbkytnc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/finwork.app (in target 'finwork' from project 'finwork')
    cd /Users/evanlu/Desktop/rebackup/finwork
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk
    builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign 22FE53F897AFEB6A2955A6C7BCB17C806EDD894A --scan-executable /Users/evanlu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/finwork-dbwrwhkrmlwsysdijoivlfbkytnc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/finwork.app/finwork --scan-folder /Users/evanlu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/finwork-dbwrwhkrmlwsysdijoivlfbkytnc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/finwork.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/evanlu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/finwork-dbwrwhkrmlwsysdijoivlfbkytnc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/finwork.app/PlugIns --scan-folder /Users/evanlu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/finwork-dbwrwhkrmlwsysdijoivlfbkytnc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods_finwork.framework --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/evanlu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/finwork-dbwrwhkrmlwsysdijoivlfbkytnc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/finwork.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --strip-bitcode-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip --emit-dependency-info /Users/evanlu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/finwork-dbwrwhkrmlwsysdijoivlfbkytnc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/finwork.build/Debug-iphoneos/finwork.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep --filter-for-swift-os

error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/evanlu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/finwork-dbwrwhkrmlwsysdijoivlfbkytnc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/finwork.app/finwork' (in target 'finwork' from project 'finwork')
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TghJ9.jpg]

And when I using Simulator. It can’t find my pod plugin.

```
/Users/evanlu/Desktop/rebackup/finwork/finwork/Database/FirestoreDatabase.swift:9:8: No such module 'FirebaseCore'
```

These are what I have been tried.

1.Clear build folder.

2.Re-install and Update podfile.

3.Check Compile Source make sure there’s not no red or grayed out files.

4.Check I didn’t using legacy build system.

5.Tracking the path

> (/Users/evanlu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/finwork-dbwrwhkrmlwsysdijoivlfbkytnc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/finwork.app/finwork).

It say "finwork.app is damaged and can’t be opened" and I check brew inside, there's no finwork file inside.

6.I try to changing Build Settings to `EXCLUDED_ARCHS = arm64 ,ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH:YES` It still unworkable.

Here’s my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'finwork' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  #use_modular_headers!
  #use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
    pod 'GoogleMaps'

    pod 'SwiftyStarRatingView'

    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'
    #pod 'FirebaseUI'
    #pod 'FirebaseUI', '>= 10.0.2'
    #pod 'GoogleSignIn'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'

    #pod 'BoringSSL-GRPC', '= 0.0.3', :modular_headers => false
    #pod 'gRPC-Core', '= 1.21.0', :modular_headers => false
    pod 'SideMenu'

    #pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

    post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
    end
end
```

Complement:

The Simulator was work in the beginning but device not.

When I running on my iPhone it show me `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMwVl.jpg]
So I changing my build setting including set `EXCLUDED_ARCHS = arm64`
、Deleted `VALID_ARCHS`、
tried to set up `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` to yes and no (neither of them working).
Then it return me `No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=arm64 arm64e i386 x86_64, EXCLUDED_ARCHS=( arm64 )).`
After this I keep my build setting `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO` , `EXCLUDED_ARCHS = arm64` and Clear build folder + Re-install podfile.
It started say `Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises`.
To solve this I change the developer account.
And then It trun me into this position.

Build settings :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBIaJ.jpg]

Any suggest will be helpful, Or on less tell me how did I massacred my Project.
Thank you for taking your time！

Update :
I just Clear build folder a few times and running by Simulator now it also showing me `Build input file cannot be found`.
But Weirdly, I didn’t do anything to solve `No such module 'FirebaseCore'`
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kJBr.jpg]

Comment: Well, how _did_ you massacre your project? If it was working before and is not working now, what did you change?

Comment: @matt I was tested  on Simulator befor. it's going well. But recently I need to using googlemap kit on my app. And It’s seem cannot running on Simulator. So likewise I trying to figure out on Stack. So this is the nightmare beginning. First , I running on my iphone but it didn’t work .It show me that  "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code". So I started changing my build setting  Including  set excluded arch、delete valid arch、trun build active architecture only to yes and no. I cannot remember all the adjust I did. But haply between these  options. Hope helpfully.

Comment: Don't tell me in a comment. Edit your question to include relevant information.

Comment: @matt Sorry for the inconvenienc. I already adding a Complement on my question. This is first time I posting on this platform. So, If anything need to be improved. Please let me know.

Comment: Another useful point might be that when you get `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`, the build log contains more information that tells you what the actual problem was.

Comment: It said unbound variable. So I according this to delete my VALID_ARCHS setting. I didn’t sure this work. But at least it showing me another issue.

Comment: I already add detailed image on my question. But,Honestly I don't really understand what does message mean.

Comment: @EvanLu Is this issue resolved? If so, please tell how you did it.

Comment: @HongLy I unloaded CocoaPod and reinstalled, and it resolved.

Comment: did you find this solution? if yes please tell me i need that

Comment: ＠Amin Rezaew As I say befor. I deleted my CocoaPod and reinstalled.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to try the same method as the image below?

`Build Settings` -> `Architectures` -> `Excluded Architectures`, `arm64`.

[image]

I don't know if it'll help, but I hope it'll be solved.

Comment: My Excluded Architectures is same with you. And I keep this option for a while. I can understanding the Architectures might be the solution. But I can’t getting how this work. I already add my build settings image on my question.  Hope this can help to provide more clue.

Comment: So you have to exclude "arm64" architecture from the build ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ARCHIVING, and nothing else worked for you:

Make sure you REMOVE arm64 under `Build Settings` -> `Architectures` -> `Release`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by going in :

build phase > pre build >

And the  adding output files (input for you ?).